# GPS unit that sends data to my computer

Tags: gps

I hope this question is accepted on superuser.com.

There are a lot of GPS tracking units you can buy that send GPS data from the unit to a company's server and let you see this data on their website. Are there any GPS units that I can configure to send the information directly to my computer? What extra computer hardware would I need for this?

Comment: If a GPS unit could send data, it would most likely be in an async serial text protocol.  A RS-232 serial port or USB port would accomplish this type of connection.

Comment: Perhaps the [hardware compatibility list](http://catb.org/gpsd/hardware.html) of gpsd will be useful?

Answer (score 2):

You're able to use all the cheap "GPS mouses" for this. You'll connect them to your computer either using Bluetooth, USB or serial cable. No matter which connection type you choose, they will get installed as a serial text device which you can easily poll using your own software or some software which already exists (search for GPS logging software).

Answer (score 2):

They pretty much all do this. [NMEA 0183](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) is the standard you'll need to code to.